# How to merge two tables into one using mongify

Tags: mysql, mongodb, migration, schema, database-migration

I am planning to migrate my application database from Mysql to Mongo with low schema changes. In my new schema I merged two Mysql tables into one Mongo collection. I want to use mongify (https://github.com/anlek/mongify) gem to populate my existing Mysql data into Mongo with newer schema.

How to do this? Is there a way in mongify to merge two Mysql tables into one?

Mysql tables

```
user
    id
    name
    nickname
    type

user_role
    id
    role
    alias
    user_id
```

I merged the above two tables into single collection in Mongo

```
user
    id
    name
    type
    role
    alias
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Left Join: (Tables will be merged)

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Export that data to sql format and upload it to mongodb

```
SELECT country INTO customerCountry
 FROM customers
 WHERE customerNumber = p_customerNumber;

    CASE customerCountry -- Here you have to see if that alias data is set
 WHEN  'USA' THEN
    SET p_shiping = '2-day Shipping'; -- here you have to write Update Query
 ELSE
    SET p_shiping = '5-day Shipping';
 END CASE;
```

I think it might help you

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply!!! The user table have "nickname" and the second table have "alias" fields. If I need to rename the field "nickname" to "alias" and I need to put the user_info.alias values in user table. How do I do this? Kindly provide your inputs...

Comment: Do you want to replace all data from user.nickname from user_role.alias colums

Comment: In that case I would suggest you to use sub query inside CASE, like If there's data inside alias then update your order nickname with that alias.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the data using **JOIN** from **MySQL** and load that data into **MongoDB:**

Try this:

```
SELECT U.id, U.name, U.type, UR.role
FROM USER U 
INNER JOIN user_role UR ON U.id = UR.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative if its difficult to merge two tables ad-hoc then run a [mongo shell script](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) post-hoc; they are very easy to program (couple o' lines of js) and simple to execute. plus one can apply any needed conversion, such as into json/bson arrays permitted in mongo but not the mysql.

assuming a user and user_role collection (or table) in mongo.

```
db.user_role.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {  
   var roles = doc.roles;
   // convert mysql format here if needed.
   //var roles_array = JSON.parse(roles) // or whatever?

   //var alias = doc.alias;
   // if alias is null empty or ??

   // dont upsert to avoid orphaned user_role records
   db.user.update({"_id": doc.user_id}, {"roles": roles, "alias", doc.alias }, {upsert: false, multi: false});

}
```

Then execute using the mongo shell

> mongo localhost:27017/test myjsfile.js